# Rails redirect_to :back with anchor not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is not working:

```
redirect_to :back, :anchor => 'visitor-comments-container'
```

How to redirect back with an anchor?

Answer (score 1):

In your application controller, store the requesting url in the session hash, which is available across multiple subsequent requests

```
session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
```

Then you can use this session into any controller action,

```
redirect_to session[:return_to]
```

Comment: `request.referer` doesn't store the anchor params.